# Java Criteria API - LowerCase a value from Database before comparing it

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I am playing around with the Criteria API but having troubles to achieve the following:

I want to compare **lowercased values from a search term** with **lowercased values from the Database**!

Lets say, I want to find some people in my database.

The following code builds up a predicate with a certain key (e.g. "firstName") and value (e.g. "John")

Here is some simplified version of what I want to achieve:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<People> query = builder.createQuery(People.class);
Root root = query.from(People.class);

Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();

predicate = builder.and(predicate,
    builder.like(root.get(key), ("%"+ value +"%").toLowerCase() ) );
```

Later I am saying, I want all people now matching this Criteria:

```
query.where(predicate);  
List<People> result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Problem is that I **also** want to lowercase the Peoples' firstName in the Database so I am able to find all 'John's with a search term of:

- 'JOHN'
- 'john'
- 'Oh'
- and so on

Thanks for help!

Cheers

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the answer of @Neil, I finalised the solution to:

```
// key and value are whitespace trimmed
predicate = builder.and(predicate,
    builder.like(builder.lower(root.get(key)),
        builder.lower(builder.literal("%"+ value +"%"))));
```

Comment: `CriteriaBuilder.lower(...)`

Comment: Don't forget to also trim them for trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thank you Neil... that was the input I needed.

Comment: @coladict Indeed!